# Does every positive number $n$ have a multiple, which has a monotonic digits in decimal basis?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

A positive integer $n$ will be called **monotonous**, if its **decimal** digits are in ascending or descending order.

---

---

For example $1111, 1122, 113355, 998850, 66655522$ and $332$ are monotonous numbers but $121, 2017$ and $5555554444445$ are not monotonous numbers.

---

---

How can I prove that for every positive integer $n$, there is a positive integer $m$ such that $nm$ is a monotonous number?

Comment: Hint: there is even always a multiple of the form 11...1100...00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\color{Purple}{\text{ The answer is }}$
$\color{Green}{\text{ YES }}$.

---

---

**Lemma(Euler)**: 
Let $n$ to be a positive ineger such that $\gcd(n,10)=1$; 
then we have:

$$ 10^{\varphi(n)} \overset{n}{\equiv} 1 \ ,$$ 
where $\varphi(n)$ euler's function; i.e. :

$$ \varphi(n) = \text{Card}\Big( 
\{ a \in \mathbb{N} \ | \ 1 \leq a \leq n \ \ \ \text{&} \ \ \ \gcd(a,n)=1 \}
\Big) \ .$$

---

---

At first assume that $\gcd(n,10)=1$;
then let $k:=\dfrac{10^{\varphi(n)}-1}{n}$, then:

$$kn = \underbrace{9 9 ... 9 9}_{\varphi(n)-\text{ times}}.$$

---

---

Now let $N$ to be a positive arbitrary integer, 
then there exist integers $r \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{ 0 \} $ 
& $s \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{ 0 \} $ and $n$; 
such that $\gcd(n,10)=1$ and $N=2^r 5^s n$.

Let $t:=\max \{ r,s \} $, and let:

$$k:=\dfrac{10^{\varphi(n)}-1}{n}.10^t \ ; $$

then we have:

$$kN = \underbrace{9 9 9 ... 9 9 9}_{\varphi(n)-\text{ times}} 
\underbrace{0 0 0 ... 0 0 0}_{t-\text{ times}} 
.$$

Comment: Note that Euler's theorem is unnecessary for proving existence.  One can just use the pigeonhole principle on residues of $10^s$ mod $n$.

Comment: @ Erick Wong , yes are right.